# crystal reports : cannot determine the queries necessary to get data for this report

Tags: crystal-reports

I've recently come across the following error in one of my crystal reports following an accounting system update.

Group #1: ? - A : This group section cannot be printed because its condition field is nonexistent or invalid.  Format the section to choose another condition field.

I've verified every database field being used to ensure it still exists for consistency and checked the formulas for that section.  No dice.  So to hopefully fix the problem, i remove the section using the Section expert.  I run the same database checks.  It then complains with the same error for Group #5.  So i remove that as well.

now I have a new and unusual error when i attempt to run 'Show Query'.

the error is: "Cannot determine the queries necessary to get data for this report"

I have tried to logon/logoff the database and verify database.  No complaints until i try to run, show query.  When I attempt to run the report, it also throws the same error.

any ideas?  Am I approaching this incorrectly? this is done in crystal reports 10.

note: 
this report is run with the sql sa user to eliminate any permission issues.

Comment: put the page number and try again

Comment: that did not work for me

Comment: All I did was remove all the links from datasets I imported into the report and everything came out perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I ended up rebuilding the entire report and re-inserting the same fields into the report along with rebuilding the groupings.  Once I did that and compared the multiple linkings, it turns out some of the table linkings were removed for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem happened to me and was in the relations between tables
See the relations in the Crystal Report, some table don't have relations:

1. Right Click on Database Fields
2. Choose Database Expert
3. Click on Links Tab
4. Check out the relations again
5. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This means that the field that defined the group is no longer in the report.

To fix this, right click the group and select 'Change Group...', then choose the appropriate field.

Comment: I tried that and it now says..  "Cannot determine the queries necessary to get data for this report" ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occurred when there was two possible start points for the query. If you go to the database expert and check the direction of the links. You may find that the links are not all heading from left to right (say). As a result, Crystal can't work out which queries to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this error in a non-grouping related setup. My data model was such:

```
A -> B -> D
A -> C -> D
```

with `->` being master detail relationships. So, in fact I was using entity D as detail of two different masters which is apparently not permitted in Crystal Reports.

Therefore, I corrected the model as follows

```
A -> B -> D
A -> C*
```

by including all attributes of D into C* and denormalizing the data when feeding it into Crystal Reports. And this was exactly the point when the run-time error started occurring. In my report using A and C*, however, I *DID NOT* replace the attributes of D by the corresponding ones of C*. So, the query engine tried to reach attributes in D coming from C* which did not work.

Replacing the attributes in D by the new ones in C* fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I fixed it by clearing links in database expert.
In .rpt file > Field Explorer right click on data Database Expert and in links tab click on Clear Links and save rpt file.
[image: DatabaseExpert-Crystal Reports Clear Links]

Answer (score 0):

I had made a copy of a report, and had this error happen, and it was because I had swapped out one of the original tables in the report for an alternate one, and the alternate one had a different column name for the key used for one of the joins, so that relationship got removed, and one of the other tables wasn't linked to. Went to database expert and readded the link on the column that was the new correct one.